# Apply superscript to the selection using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, superscript

Can any one help me how can I apply superscript to the selection in my content editable div using javascript?

I have this div and a button:

```
<div contenteditable="true">Apple Grapes Orange</div>
<input type="button" onclick="applySuperScript" value="Apply SuperScript">
```

Suppose if I have selected the text "Orange" from my content editable div and click on button, javascript should be called to apply super script for the text "Orange".

Comment: I suppose you'll have to get the current selection and wrap it in a *sup* element. You'll also have to update the surrounding text to remove the selected text and break it into one or two text nodes. What have you tried? There are surely answers for this here already.

Comment: PS. Checkout the [*selection API*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) on MDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight modification to the html.

```
<div id='text' contenteditable="true">Apple Grapes Orange</div>
<input type="button" id='super'  value="Apply SuperScript">
```

This is our click handler

```
document.getElementById('super').onclick = function() {
 var textarea = document.getElementById('text');
 var anchorOffset = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
 var focusOffset = window.getSelection().focusOffset;
 var str = textarea.innerHTML.substring(anchorOffset,focusOffset)
 textarea.innerHTML= textarea.innerHTML.replace(str,'<sup>'+str+'</sup>');
 };
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krishnakumarm777/0jwkctg8/).

Comment: Wow! Krishna, your solution works perfectly except the below scenario. Suppose if I have div content like this:
    <div id='text' contenteditable="true">Orange Apple Grapes Orange</div>

if I select "Orange" from the last, first Orange text shows in superscript

Comment: Try this @ShrinathShetty. `var str = textarea.innerHTML;
textarea.innerHTML= str.substring(0,anchorOffset) + '<sup>'+str.substring(anchorOffset,focusOffset)+'</sup>' + str.substring(focusOffset);`